# SharePoint Hosted App Event Receiver

Tags: event-handlers, app

Is it possible to create an event receiver on a list deployed in SharePoint hosted App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible to add an event receiver to a list in sharepoint hosted app. Event receivers can only be added to provider hosted and autohosted apps. Notice that as soon as you try to add remote event receiver to sharepoint hosted app it adds a remote web to the project and turns into cloud hosted app.

Comment: So how do I catch an event if I add an item to a list in SharePoint Hosted App?

Comment: Maybe you can work with an workflow that contains a custom activity?

Comment: Agree with @Sascha, workflow may be the right approach.